# LuaTeX colored boxes with rounded corners

Tags: color, boxes, luatex

What is the simplest way to make coloured boxes  with rounded corners in `luatex`?
With `xelatex` I used `pstricks` and it was simple, but with `luatex` it is not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest method is to use the [mdframed](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) or the [tcolorbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package (example for `tcolorbox`: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox)
package, which use `TikZ`. You can integrate with [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) as per the following MWE example, which uses both packages. It also runs the code and typesets the example. Please ensure you have the latest versions for all and run as LuaLaTeX (tcolorbox was updated recently).

[image]

I have used the same base code from another post of mine [How can I produce vertical white space in a table with LuaLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48493/how-can-i-produce-vertical-white-space-in-a-table-with-lualatex/48496#48496), which I posted tonight. Have a look also at that post for `unframed` boxes (they look better to me).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]TeX, [primitive]TeX,Pascal}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{luacode} % loads luatexbase as well
\newcommand\emphasis[2][blue]{\lstset{emph={exec,if,then,else,do,end,while,for,print,sprint,directlua,#2},
   emphstyle={\ttfamily\textcolor{#1}}}}%
\lstset{language={[LaTeX]TeX},
      stepnumber=1,numbersep=5pt, 
      numberstyle={\footnotesize\color{gray}},%firstnumber=last,
      breaklines=true,
      framesep=5pt,
      basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
      showstringspaces=false,
      keywordstyle=\ttfamily\textcolor{blue},
      stringstyle=\color{orange},
      commentstyle=\color{black},
      rulecolor=\color{gray!10},
      breakatwhitespace=true,
      showspaces=false,  % shows spacing symbol
      backgroundcolor=\color{gray!15}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\emphasis{return,repeat,until,function,local}
\begin{tcblisting}{}
\begin{luacode}
-- example adapted from
-- http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Happy_numbers
function boxit(color, var, s)
 zz="\\mdframed[roundcorner=3pt, leftmargin=2cm,innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt, innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt, innerlinewidth=0pt, middlelinewidth=0pt,outerlinewidth=1pt, outerlinecolor=red]"..var.."\\endmdframed"
 return zz
end
function digits(n)
  if n > 0 then return n \% 10, digits(math.floor(n/10)) end
end
function sumsq(a, ...)
  return a and a ^ 2 + sumsq(...) or 0
end
local happy = setmetatable({true, false, false, false}, {
      __index = function(self, n)
         self[n] = self[sumsq(digits(n))]
         return self[n]
      end } )
i, j = 0, 8
repeat
   i, j = happy[j] and (tex.sprint(boxit(violet, j, " ")) or i+1) or i, j + 1
until i == 17 --or j > 999
\end{luacode}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would recommend `tcolorbox`. `pstricks` allows no page breaks so it's the nearest.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The post has both:) Can you help with the style to get it nearer to `boxit` in the link I posted in the answer? I am not very familiar with your package.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: I compiled the `tcolorbox` example with lualatex and it just worked.

Comment: @Stephen -- Thanks for the test and the edit for the links. The `tcblisting` I used is one of the environments of `tcolorbox`. Great package.

Comment: `tcolorbox` is really nice, thank you very much!

Comment: @SadChi They are both great packages. If you need to break across pages use `mdframed`, `tcolorbox` is very suited for notes, manuals etc.